# Inner Objects vs companion objects in Scala

Tags: scala

Can anyone suggest the difference between following

```
Class A{
 object A{
 }
}
```

and

```
Class A{

}
object A{

}
```

Comment: In the 1st case every instance of `A` will have its own separate `object A`. In the 2nd case every instance of `A` will share access to a single, unique, `object A`.

Answer (score 1):

From scala doc:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html

An object with the same name as a class is called a companion object. Conversely, the class is the object’s companion class. A companion class or object can access the private members of its companion. **Use a companion object for methods and values which are not specific to instances of the companion class.**

For first case:

you can use the object like `new A().A`

Answer (score 1):

the difference is that in the first case you have a path-dependant-type.

Let's reformat your code and separate the cases so it could compile:

```
class A {
  object A
}

class B
object B
```

Now notice that:

```
new A().A == new A().A // false
B == B // true
```

So while the A of the first instance is not the same as the A of the second instance, B is exactly the same.

I would like to add that is not a question of inner objects vs classes.
It would have been the same even if the inner type was a class instead of an object. I suggest that you read [this great post](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/13/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-13-path-dependent-types.html) by Daniel Westheide, but basically let's define a `Character` (which happens to be a class at this time) inside a `Franchise`:

```
class Franchise(name: String) {
  case class Character(name: String)
  def createFanFictionWith(
    lovestruck: Character,
    objectOfDesire: Character): (Character, Character) = (lovestruck, objectOfDesire)
}
```

Now given two different franchises, `starTrek` and `starWars`, characters from the same franchise will be from the same type, while characters from different franchises will be from another type:

```
// creating two franchise
val starTrek = new Franchise("Star Trek")
val starWars = new Franchise("Star Wars")

// quark and jadzia belong to the same franchise (Star Trek)
val quark = starTrek.Character("Quark")
val jadzia = starTrek.Character("Jadzia Dax")

// luke and yoda belong to the same franchise (Star Wars)
val luke = starWars.Character("Luke Skywalker")
val yoda = starWars.Character("Yoda")
```

So now quark can have a crush on jadzia, and luke can have a crush on yoda:

```
starTrek.createFanFictionWith(lovestruck = quark, objectOfDesire = jadzia)
starWars.createFanFictionWith(lovestruck = luke, objectOfDesire = yoda)
```

But jadzia cannot have a crush on luke, since they type of jadzia is `starTrek.Character` but the type of luke is `starWars.Character`:

```
starTrek.createFanFictionWith(lovestruck = jadzia, objectOfDesire = luke) // DOES NOT COMPILE :)
```

This example is from Daniel's post, and again - I highly recommend that you read it.